# import csv file from rails to oracle database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, csv

I am working on a simple webapp and I connected Oracle database through the 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter' and oci8.

I have a web page where I would like to select a csv file and send these data to oracle.

Actually I can retrieve properly entries from my oracle database without any issue and when I create an order via my webapp I can insert the post into my oracle database either.

Here is my code in models/commande.rb :

```
class Commande < ApplicationRecord
   require 'csv'

   def self.import(file) 
     CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
       Commande.create! row.to_hash
     end
   end
end
```

controller/commandes_controller :

```
def import
   Commande.import(params[:file])
   redirect_to root_url, notice: "Activity Data Imported!"
end
```

views/commandes/index.html.erb

```
<h4>Import pool orders</h4>
  <%= form_tag import_commandes_path, multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import CSV" %>
<% end %>
```

router :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :commandes do
    collection {post :import}
  end
  resources :ressources

  root to: "commandes#index"
   # For details on the DSL available within this file, see 
 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

when I select my csv file and click import, I have an error message : 
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError blabala table's fields.

I succeed one time (and I don't know how actually) and received my notice : "activity data imported" but any data were forwarded to my oracle database.

Is anyone has an idea ?

Comment: Can you post the error and is "row.to_hash" output matching correctly to Commandes fields?

Comment: All fields are existing in my db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
  Commande.create! row.to_hash
end
```

Well your code should be working as you have it. Somehow it's outputting the rows incorrectly. 
Which version of Ruby do you have?

As you can see from the picture what's happening is that it's providing an hash like 
`{ "user_id;name" => "3;Laure" }`
, where it should be 
`{ 'user_id': "3", 'name': "Laure" }`

It's raising the error because your model doesn't have a column `"user_id;name"`, it has two columns, one `user_id` another `name`

So either the CSV you're opening is wrongly formatted or your ruby version is outdated.

You could make this work by mapping directly the csv columns to the fields on the model, like

```
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: false) do |row|
  split_row = row.split(';')
  Commande.create!(user_id: split_row[0], name: split_row[1])
end
```

Comment: I have an updated ruby's version : ruby 2.4.0p0. But thanks a lot, I spent 2 days trying to make it works. I just had to removed the header in the csv file and to used the snippet you provide. However I still get an error, an error that I met before. It works when I import the csv (datas are forwaded to Oracle) but I am getting (null) nil entries inside Oracle and when I want to see the users's dashboard, I have no text printed. Do you have an idea ? 'cause I met this error before when I used to place atr_accessor in my model.

Comment: we can see that the sql request is not working properly : SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "USERS" ("CREATED_AT", "UPDATED_AT", "ID") VALUES (:a1, :a2, :a3) - I don't have 'user_id' and 'name'.

Comment: I solved my issue by changing a little by the code you provide. Now it works pretty good :) thank you again

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing the picture. Easy to see all the informations. 
As you will see, I tried with another table "users". I created the table through rails and fetch with a db:migrate to oracle. same error as described bellow :

[screenshot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOJi5.jpg)